# How to store JavaScript functions into documents in mongoose?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to store some data and associated `functions` into the `mongodb document`.

```
{name:"data1",event:function(){ /* some code */ }}
{name:"data2",event:function(){ /* some other code */ }}
```

i am using `mongoose.js` `ORM` for my project. How should i write my `schema` for this?

quoting from the mongoose [guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

> The permitted `SchemaTypes` are `String`, `Number`, `Date`, `Buffer`,
>   `Boolean`, `Mixed`, `ObjectId` and `Array`.

But if you check with the `datatypes` allowed by `mongodb`, you can find ways to store js function as mentioned in [mongo-db-data-types-article](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html#mongo-db-data-types)

> Code class a special class that let’s you store javascript functions
>   in Mongo DB, can also provide a scope to run the method in

I couldnt find the above datatype on mongoose. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it for a map/reduce?

Comment: i simply want to store custom JavaScript functions with each document and retrieve them back.

Comment: Mongoose plugins can be found by the [keyword "mongoose" in NPM](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/mongoose/1/), but the far I could see, there isn't anything for the Code class datatype yet.

Comment: what are you actualy trying to achieve by storing functions in db?

Comment: @hilarudeens : storing some events in the db to fire when users select them active.

Comment: My assumption is, you need to execute the function which is doing different operation based on each document in db. Then you can store them as string and later you can execute by use eval function.

Answer (score 1):

This module adds function support to Mongoose: https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-function